# Reading the value of a struct/object in a Frida intercepted method

Tags: reverse-engineering, disassembly, frida

Suppose I have a C# method with the following signature

```cs
public virtual void DoSomething(int index, int value, List<int> results)
```

I've had success so far using Frida to hook into the method call like so

```
Interceptor.attach(Module.findBaseAddress("library.so").add(0x123456), {
   onEnter(args) {
      log(args[2]) // here I'd like to print the values of the list
   }
})
```

Logging out the pointer to the argument itself gives me a value like `0x1`. If the pointer was a for a primitive I'd have used something like `args[2].readUtf8String()` to read the value but I'm not sure how to approach a `List<int>` or really any complex object.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are debugging a native library (library.so). If that's the case, I'm afraid that it won't be so trivial to access the underlaying attributes, methods and so of any class, as many concepts that are valid and make sense for C#/IL are just treated different at lower level.

For instance, the function you provided:

```cs
public virtual void DoSomething(int index, int value, List<int> results)
```

Would probably get mapped to something like this in its native equivalent:

```cpp
void DoSomething(ThisClass* this, int32_t index, int32_t value, StructForListOfInts* results)";
```

Therefore, in order to access individual attributes for complex objets, you need to know the underlaying structure in advance so you can "move around" to the specific offsets you want. I imagine this is not very useful by itself as you still need the struct but if you are able to provide more details about this, I'd be happy to keep looking at it :)